# Distribution of cumulative sojourn times in a (continuous time) Markov Chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I hope that I have reached the correct forum for this-else I am happy to move it to another site.

For a couple of days now, I have been pondering the following question, but cannot come up with a neat solution:

Assume a continuous time Markov chain on two states, $x_t=a$ or $x_t=b$ with constant transition rates $\lambda_{a\to b}\equiv\alpha$ and $\lambda_{b\to a} \equiv \beta$, i.e. the transition rate matrix is

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-\alpha & \alpha\\
\beta & -\beta
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I am now looking for the **probability density function** (or any sensible approximation thereof) of the **cumulative time the chain is in state $a$** during a time interval $[0,T]$ given some initial state or initial state distribution $x_0$, $I\equiv \int_0^T \mathbf{1}_{x_s=a|x_0}ds$,

$$
\begin{align}
f(t)=p(I=t)\mathord{?}
\end{align}
$$

From a simulation study, I already "know" that for $\alpha, \beta$ fixed and $T \to \infty$, the distribution converges to a normal distribution (in effect, we are adding exponentially distributed RVs no?). I also know that the mean time - and hence the distribution mean time of being in state $a$ - is (of course) $T\times\pi_a$, i.e. the total period times the stationary distribution probability of being in state $a$.

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: https://www.jds-online.com/files/JDS-1068.pdf. See in page 6 $f_0(t,T)$ and $f_1(t,T).$ Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks! Wow, it truly looks like what I am looking for. I'll program this during the next days and update my comment here if you want to make it a full answer (to be accepted) later on.

Comment: Great, don't worry about the accepted answer thing. Good luck with the implementation.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it worked, thanks for letting me know.